# How to run a simple Python script without writing a complete Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have set up Docker Toolbox on a Win 10 machine. I have some simple single file Python scripts that I want to run in Docker, just for learning purpose.
Started learning Docker today, and Python 3 days ago.

I assume I have set up Docker correctly, I can run the example hello-world image. No error messages during setup.

I am following an instruction from here https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application,
 which says:

*If you only need to run a simple script (with a single file), you can avoid writing a complete Dockerfile. In the examples below, assume you store my_script.py in /usr/src/widget_app/, and you want to name the container my-first-python-script:*

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-first-python-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/widget_app python:3 python my_script.py
```

If I type **pwd**, it shows:

```
/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
```

And the script I want to run is located here:

```
C:\Docker\Python\my_script.py
```

This is what I think should work:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-first-python-script -v "$PWD":/c/Docker/Python python:3 python my_script.py
```

No matter how I try to specify the file directory, I get an error:

```
python: can't open file 'my_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: The container knows nothing about the `/c/Docker/Python` directory.  You can name that directory inside the container anything you want, but you also need a `-w` option to set the current directory inside the container or to give an absolute (container-side) path as the script argument to `python`.

Comment: (This doesn’t seem like an especially effective use of Docker to me though; it’d be vastly simpler and a much better developer experience to just use a Python interpreter on your host.)

Comment: @DavidMaze
I knew this was not a good use of Docker, but I figured I would try anyway, as it was part of the tutorial. I am curious though, are there any real life use cases this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `-v "$PWD":/c/Docker/Python`, you are saying you want to link your current working directory to the path `/c/Docker/Python` in the container, which isn't what you want to do. What you are trying to do is link `C:\Docker\Python\` on your host to the container folder `/usr/src/widget_app`.

This command will put your script inside the container path `/usr/src/widget_app`, then run it:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-first-python-script -v /c/Docker/Python:/usr/src/widget_app python:3 python /usr/src/widget_app/my_script.py
```

Comment: Thanks! The file is found now, but I'm getting a different error:
/usr/local/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/usr/src/my_script.py'
And my python script is simply print("Hello world"), no libraries used.

Comment: docker run -it --rm --name my-python-script -v /c/Docker/Python:/usr/src python:3 python /usr/src/my_script.py

Comment: What is the output of `docker run -it --rm --name my-python-script -v /c/Docker/Python:/usr/src python:3 cat /usr/src/my_script.py` ?